# NSNotification not shown when running the code in a console hello world application

Tags: macos, cocoa, notifications, toast, nsnotifications

I try to send a native notification from my console application but nothing shows up when running it. Am I missing something needed to push a notification?

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSUserNotification* notification = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];
        notification.identifier = @"unique-id";
        notification.title = @"Hello!!!";
        notification.subtitle = @"How are you?";
        notification.informativeText = @"This is a test??????";
        notification.soundName = NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName;

        [[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] deliverNotification:notification];
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for NSUserNotificationCenter:

> When a user notification’s delivery date has been reached, or it is
>   manually delivered, the notification center may display the
>   notification to the user. The user notification center reserves the
>   right to decide if a delivered user notification is presented to the
>   user. For example, it may suppress the notification if the application
>   is already frontmost (the delegate can override this action). The
>   application can check the result of this decision by examining the
>   presented property of a delivered user notification.

You should check the following to see if they are true or false:

```
// make sure the notification was delivered
[[[NSUerNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] deliveredNotifications] containsObject:notification]
// see if the notification was presented
notification.presented
```